# How to get values from mix of namespace and non-namespace XML with

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

Given the XML and related PHP, below how can I get the namespaced values in the same way that I'm able to get the non-namespaced values? I've been referring to a number of other SE QAs about this, but can't seem to get it right.  An help is appreciated. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:psg="http://b3000.example.net:3000/psg_namespace/">
  <channel>
    <title>Example</title>
    <description>example stuff</description>
    <item>
      <psg:eventId>406589</psg:eventId>
      <psg:duration>3482</psg:duration>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source, null, true);
foreach($xml->channel->item as $entry){
    echo $entry->title;          // This works
    echo $entry->description;    // This works
    echo $entry->item->duration  // Pseudo of what I need
}
```

How to get Duration? My attempts with variations such as this have failed

```
$namespaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
$psg = $item->children($namespaces['psg']);
```

**Update**

While it wasn't the answer I was actually looking for, I have to accept the first answer that got me trying things leading to the actual problem - "operator error"!  This DOES work....my problem was in trying to figure it out, I was debugging with `echo print_r($psg, true)`.  That was showing the result as a SimpleXmlObject, which then got me chasing how to get those properties - All I had to do was assign the property instead of echoing it.

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $entry){
    $psg = $item->children($ns['psg']);
    $title    = (string) $item->title;
    $duration = (string) $psg->duration;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the method `children` from http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php where you pass in the namespace and tell it it's a prefix, to get at that node?

Comment: Hi! The convention of this site is that questions and answers remain separate, [even if that means answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). So the "Update" you've added should really be an answer, which you can then accept to show future readers that this is what solved your problem. You can upvote Robbie Averill's answer to show it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use a combination of [XPath with namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source, null, true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('psg', 'http://b3000.example.net:3000/psg_namespace/');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//item/psg:duration') as $duration) {
    echo $duration, PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you don't want to declare the namespace literally, you can retrieve it from the document and add it/them dynamically:

```
foreach ($xml->getDocNamespaces() as $key => $namespace) {
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace($key, $namespace);
}
```